With node javascript : How use OpenAI api as OCR for a local image?
I try to use openApi's api as OCR in node with gpt-4o model from a local image .
const api_key = "mykey"
import OpenAI from 'openai';
import fs from "fs"

const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: api_key, 
});

function convertToBase64(filePath) {
    const bitmap = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    return Buffer.from(bitmap).toString('base64');
}

(async () => {
    const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
        model: "gpt-4o",
        messages: [
            {
                content: [
                    {
                        role: 'user',
                        content: 'Return me the text of this image.'
                    },
                    {
                        role: 'system',
                        content: 'image_url',
                        image_url: `data:image/png;base64${convertToBase64('./image12.png')}`
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    });

    console.log(chatCompletion.choices[0].message.content);

})();

I have the error message

(node:23388) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is
deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead. (Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created) url-state-machine.js:2 Uncaught BadRequestError Error: 400 Invalid
chat format. Expected 'role' fields in all messages.
at generate (path\node_modules\openai\error.mjs:41:20)
at makeStatusError (path\node_modules\openai\core.mjs:268:25)
at makeRequest (path\node_modules\openai\core.mjs:311:30)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues:95:5) error.mjs:41 Process exited with code 1

Do you know how to do it?

Your format of messages isn't in compliance of this example in the docs

The role property should be located on the same level as the content:
    messages: [
      {
        role: 'user',
        content: [
          {
            content: 'Return me the text of this image.'
          },
          {
            content: 'image_url',
            image_url: `data:image/png;base64${convertToBase64('./image12.png')}`
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

Please note that your code also has other issues, as @ITgoldman pointed out.
